# Drop down list and Selenium with Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to develop code to do data scraping on an energy comparison website. The problem is that in this website it is included some drop down list (maybe AJAX, but I do not know), so even though I type the name correct when I go to submit my info the page gives me two errors.

**-Insert your house surface (it shouldn't tell me because it is a form that is getting away when I press "I know my consumes")** [ONGOING]

-You have to insert your city (even though I type the whole name, I do not know hot to click an item of the drop-down list from selenium) [SOLVED]

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime
import os

#saving url
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
my_url = 'https://comparateur.selectra.info'
#opening my connection and downloading the page
browser.get(my_url)
button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('custom-control-indicator')[-1]
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
start = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=\"no-cookie\"]/form/button')
start.click()
comp = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=\"form-comparaison\"]/fieldset[1]/div[1]/div/label[1]')
comp.click()
cons = browser.find_element_by_class_name('know_consumption_yes')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cons)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cons)
kw = browser.find_element_by_id('annual-elec')
kw.send_keys("3200")
ville = browser.find_element_by_id('city')
ville.send_keys("Paris (75001)")
submit = browser.find_element_by_id('compare-offer')
submit.click()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The list is here:

[image: here]

Just peek what you need.

Firstly you have to type name (better full name) in input field, then wait a bit(2-3 seconds) before the list will appear, then you can locate your element from dropdown lost and click on it.

For example:

```
ville = browser.find_element_by_id('city')
ville.send_keys("Paris (75001)")
driver.implicitly_wait(2) # waits 2 sec
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Paris (75001)')]") # locate the dropdown elem
element.click() # click on it
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the list but how to pick one element? I tried to create a WebElement with the id (ui-id-1135) and then click it but it is telling me  "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: I have added some explanation to my answer with a sample code, please have a look

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"ui-id-1135"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.79)

Comment: Yes it is because the `id` is dynamic, I have added an `xPath`, that should work, please try it

Comment: mmm still not working, it says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: wait i made it, i changed elements to element and it works!!

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved this issue. Still ongoing the other one. When I I click the submit button it is telling me "Pour accéder à la comparaison, merci de renseigner votre surface d'habitation." even though this option get disabled when i input by myself the amount of KW any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: I dont know what `Pour accéder à la comparaison, merci de renseigner votre surface d'habitation.` mean, can you translate it? ))

Comment: It is "to enter in the comparison, please indicate the surface of your house".

But I shouldn't receive that message because I decided to manually input the number of KW of the offer.

Comment: Please show where to decide it, share a screenshot or something

Comment: https://ibb.co/nck9iT

even though i click on 'oui' and the second form goes away, it still tells me i have to insert it, while clicking 'oui' manually there is no problem

Comment: it is strange, I can suggest you to click 2 times on this button, or after clicking first time wait a bit. Lets say 2 seconds

Comment: i tried clicking 2 times, waiting 2 seconds, clicking 'oui' 'no' and 'oui' again but still the same

Comment: i found the solution adding this browser.execute_script("arguments[0].checked = true;", cons) after clicking the button thank you anyway

Comment: Glad to hear it! Have a nice day!

Comment: @downvoter I have edited my answer, so probably it makes sense to cancel your downvote

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your selectors are correct as there is no html,

Try these methods, they should mostly solve the issue,

```
driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('your_select_element_id here'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Your option text here')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('option_value here')
```

Also, refer the answer to this question

[What is the correct way to select an  using Selenium's Python WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver)

Comment: The html is in the website I have in my code. I don't think I can select the drop-down list because it is not an element in the HTML.

Comment: I tried to follow the explanation in your link but it is giving me this error 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: ville = browser.find_element_by_id('city')

for option in ville:

    if option.text == 'Paris (75001)':

        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver

        break

ville.send_keys("Paris (75001)")

submit = browser.find_element_by_id('compare-offer')

submit.click()